# Facebook Share - Logo images not showing up as thumbnails

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, share

I know this has been asked many times, yet I have not found an answer that seems to work.
I am currently sharing a page with one or more images on it on Facebook.
The link is shortened using bit.ly (not sure if this is important, but I thought i'd mention it anyway).

All the images show up as thumbnails on Facebook, except the one I need (the logo image).  The logo image can change based on who the user accessing the page is, but they are all approximately the same size.

I have investigated the issue and haven't found a solution yet.

My url to share the link is below:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://bit.ly/9hKNT5&t=Hello!
```

My code to set the logo image as a thumbnail on Facebook is below:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://qa.socialnetworks.iloverewards.com/program_content/program/care/en/logo.png"/>
```

Is there anything i'm missing or anyway else to force the image to be a thumbnail?

I am also curious if there are any restrictions on images that can be shared.
The logo images is a .png file with dimensions anywhere from 700 x 50 to 250 x 120.  Perhaps the size or file type is the reason the logo's aren't showing up?

Thanks in advance,

- Mike

Comment: I've updated the url's to be real url's from a mock version of the real site so they should work for people.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL doesn't even pass the linter for me

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F9F5dfgh%26t%3DHello!

Comment: Sorry, I might add that the url in the code above is not a valid url.  For security reasons, I can't share the real url.  However, it's the exact same as my code except that the url is different.

Comment: I tried the Linter test and the logo image is picked up as an image icon.  Is this what you'd expect from an image that isn't showing up as a thumbnail.

Comment: If you can't give us access to page (is it behind password?), how Facebook can get there?

Comment: The link above does work.  I updated it with a link of a mock version of our real site.  Facebook can hit both the mock site and the real site.  It's the thumbnail that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the mistake was, that I had an png, with the file-extension of a jpg.